# Pick image from gallery takes too long

Tags: android, image-processing, android-asynctask, android-imagebutton

in my app user can click on an image button then chooses an image from gallery then that image sets to image button. But the problem is that for images with sizes of order 5MB or larger, it takes very long to back from gallery to my activity and the screen becomes black for some seconds. I don't do any operation on selected image, I only want to get the path of selected image by user.

It seems that image picking can't be done within AsyncTask. So how can we handle image picking process for big images.

when I pick a big image from gallery in logcat I receive

> The application may be doing too much work on its main thread.

Comment: "I only want to get the path of selected image by user" -- there is no path. Beyond that, please provide a [mcve].

Comment: Can you show us what you are trying to do in your `onActivityResult`, if you use that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As Nabin answered, you can do image processing in an `AsyncTask`, I created a small example for you:

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    public static final int PICK_IMAGE = 1;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        Toolbar toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
        setSupportActionBar(toolbar);

        FloatingActionButton fab = (FloatingActionButton) findViewById(R.id.fab);
        fab.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                Intent intent = new Intent();
                intent.setType("image/*");
                intent.setAction(Intent.ACTION_GET_CONTENT);
                startActivityForResult(Intent.createChooser(intent, "Select Picture"), PICK_IMAGE);
            }
        });
    }

    @Override
    public void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
        if (requestCode == PICK_IMAGE) {
            Uri imagePath = data.getData();
            new LoadImageDataTask(imagePath).execute();
        }
    }

    private class LoadImageDataTask extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, Bitmap> {

        private Uri imagePath;

        LoadImageDataTask(Uri imagePath) {
            this.imagePath = imagePath;
        }

        @Override
        protected Bitmap doInBackground(Void... params) {
            try {
                InputStream imageStream = getContentResolver().openInputStream(imagePath);
                return BitmapFactory.decodeStream(imageStream);
            } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
                Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "The file " + imagePath + " does not exists",
                        Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }
            return null;
        }

        @Override
        protected void onPostExecute(Bitmap bitmap) {
            super.onPostExecute(bitmap);
            Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "I got the image data, with size: " +
                            Formatter.formatFileSize(MainActivity.this, bitmap.getByteCount()),
                    Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
    }
}
```

Doing work in the background, prevents your app from freezing. I can even choose images with 60MB+ size pretty fast.

Comment: I needed an example, it helped me.

Answer (score 1):

Image picking may not be done inside an `AsyncTask`. But decoding bitmap from the image file/Uri can surely be done in `AsyncTask`.

Also since you are using the image in an `ImageButton`, you may not need to use the full size image. Use `Options#inSampleSize` to reduce the size of the decoded bitmap.